# Flutter on Apple Silicon M1 Mac Mini: iOS SIM Error

Tags: ios, flutter, apple-m1

I finally got Flutter to build for ios on the new Apple Silicon M1 Mac Mini.
Building is OK but when I try to run on the iOS Sim, I got the following errors:

```
Xcode build done.                                           28.9s
[VERBOSE-2:profiler_metrics_ios.mm(184)] Error retrieving thread information: (ipc/send) invalid destination port
```

My searches on the net did not help. Anyone encounter this as well?

Comment: include a flutter doctor output here

Comment: Switching to master or beta channel fixed the issue. See: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/71395